# Parse data in Python request

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to run a query with an API to get a piece of information. However, I get too much data. I am looking for a way to only get a specific value, which is the number after `"totalItemCount"`. How can I search for the value of `"totalItemCount"` which shows up like `"totalItemCount":number,`. How can I run the API query search for number for `"totalItemCount"`? So far, I have code:

```py
import requests
import json

##headers
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key':'apikeyNumber'
}

response = requests.get('https://app.application.com/api/v3/agents/1', headers=headers)

data = response.json()

data_str = json.dumps(data, indent=2)

print(data_str)
```

Output: Large amount of data, a snippet:

```py
...
      "LastRebootTime": "2022-11-10T15:25:44Z",
      "OSVersion": "21H2",
      "OSBuild": "19044.2251",
      "OfficeFullVersion": "16.0.10391.20029",
    }
  ],
  "totalItemCount": 1088,
  "page": 1,
  "itemsInPage": 20,
  "totalPages": 55,
  "prevLink": "",
}
```

Not sure on the parsing after running the api query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is unclear as to whether you want to retrieve the data from the parsed json or specialize the request so that only the `"totalItemCount": 1088` data are returned. If you want to reduce what comes back in the request then the only way to determine this is to read the documentation for the API you are using. If not there you can try asking on a help forum for the API service-assuming they host one.

If you want to retrieve only the data from the parsed response then you can use the dictionary `.get()` method. The default for the second argument is `None` which specifies the value if this key is not present in the response. E.g.

```
import requests
import json


headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key':'apikeyNumber'
}


response = requests.get('https://app.application.com/api/v3/agents/1', headers=headers)

data = response.json()
data_str = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
totalItemCount = data_str.get("totalItemCount", 0)
```

will give you a value in `totalItemCount` of `0` if the key-value pair is not present for any reason. Otherwise it will return the value present in the response.